# How to update Xcode project info.plist build version from ANT script using replaceregexp

Tags: ios, xcode, ant

I am trying to build and package my iOS app using ANT script. I am able to build the app and create the ipa file from terminal using ANT script. Now, there is a requirement to update the build number and version with the user provided values in the Xcode info.plist file. In my project I am using the below code to update android app version number in manifest.xml file.

```
<replaceregexp
file="AndroidManifest.xml"
match='android:versionCode="(\d+)"'
replace='android:versionCode="${versionCode}"' />

<replaceregexp
file="AndroidManifest.xml"
match='android:versionName="(\d+\.\d+)\.\d+"'
replace='android:versionName="${versionName}"' />
```

I am trying my best to achieve the same in iOS xocde also. But I am unable to do so as I am new to ANT. Please suggest me on this. Thanks a lot in advance…..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to edit the Info.plist. Luckily, Apple provides PlistBuddy (found in [Developer Tools](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/)), which contains a bunch of useful methods to update a plist file.

```
<exec executable="/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy">
    <arg value="-c"/>
    <arg value ="Set :CFBundleVersion ${myVersion}"/>
    <arg value="${pathToXcodeProject}/Info.plist"/>
</exec>
```

Or, you can use the [PlistBuddy Ant Task](https://github.com/pekalicious/PlistBuddyAntTask), which does that in one line:

```
<plistbuddy property="CFBundleVersion" value="${myVersion}" plistFile="${pathToXcodeProject}/Info.plist" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot… That's what I wanted….

Comment: One more problem I have in my ANT build script. Mine is a cordova based iOS project and thus we have javascript files in our project folder. Now, from ANT script, I want to update one javascript file. That file is having all the configuration stuffs. I need to update the values of some variables. Do you have any solution for this also?

Comment: Yes, the way I do it is have a template properties file somewhere outside the project with the following format: server.url = #SERVER_URL#, server.user = #SERVER_USER#, etc... I then copy that to where it has to be copied and do some replacements... here is an example: [http://pastebin.com/gSfiNxYm](http://pastebin.com/gSfiNxYm)

Comment: Thanks.. I did not figure out completely.. may be I will try this later.. I have posted another question just now. Could you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/21466526/2035845 and try to answer..